# Parsing special characters in a for loop from a file to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to set a variable (Let's say, filehash is the variable name) from a file using batch file. Alas, I was stuck facing these two problems:

1. When it contains special characters, especially exclamation mark(s) as I'm using enableDelayedExpansion.
2. While doing that, I need to change `&amp;` to & as well.

I've tried several solutions provided from various sources but none would fit my requirements.

Here's my current code:

```
@echo off
set grep=binaries\grep.exe
set fileindex=binaries\index.htm
set count=0
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (crc.dat) do ( 
set count=!count! + 1
set filehash=%%a
%grep% --ignore-case -w "!filehash!" %fileindex%>> list.dat
)
```

And an example of what's inside the crc.dat file:

```
Kabooom! Kablooey!
Kaboom &amp; Kablooey
```

And the result using my current code above in list.dat:

```
Kabooom Kablooey
Kaboom &amp; Kablooey
```

The result that I'm expecting in list.dat:

```
Kabooom! Kablooey!
Kaboom & Kablooey
```

I hope I conveyed my problem properly and thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please update your code with the set statements you are using for grep and fileindex.

Comment: Edited the post to include the set statements for both grep and fileindex

Comment: Why are you assigning the FOR variable to an environmental variable? Just use the FOR variable with GREP and then you do not need delayed expansion enabled.

Comment: That's actually what Steve's been proposing as part of his solution which works for the exclamation. We're trying to dig further about how to replace the ampersand tho'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `&amp;` by `&` in the **input** of `grep`, use this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "grep=binaries\grep.exe"
set "fileindex=binaries\index.htm"
set "file=crc.dat"
set "list=list.dat"

rem // Initialise counter:
set /A "count=0"
> "%list%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
        rem // Increment counter:
        set /A "count+=1"
        rem // Assign line string to variable:
        set "lineitem=%%a"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Do sub-string replacement:
        set "lineitem=!lineitem:&amp;=&!"
        rem // Execute `grep` command line:
        "!grep!" --ignore-case -w "!lineitem!" "!fileindex!"
        endlocal
    )
)
rem // Return counter:
echo/%count%

endlocal
```

To replace `&amp;` by `&` in the **output** of `grep`, use this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "grep=binaries\grep.exe"
set "fileindex=binaries\index.htm"
set "file=crc.dat"
set "list=list.dat"

rem // Initialise counter:
set /A "count=0"
> "%list%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
        rem // Increment counter:
        set /A "count+=1"
        rem // Execute `grep` command line and capture its output by `for /F`:
        for /F "delims=" %%b in ('^""%grep%" --ignore-case -w "%%a" "%fileindex%"^"') do (
            rem // Assign `grep` output to variable:
            set "lineitem=%%b"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Do sub-string replacement:
            set "lineitem=!lineitem:&amp;=&!"
            rem // Return modified string:
            echo(!lineitem!
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
rem // Return counter:
echo/%count%

endlocal
```

In general, to handle strings with exclamation marks, you must toggle delayed expansion, so that normal `%`-expanded variables and `for` variable references like `%%a` become expanded with delayed expansion disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution which is `delayedExpansion`-free and able to replace `&amp;` to `&`.

```
@echo off
set grep=binaries\grep.exe
set fileindex=binaries\index.htm
set count=0

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (crc.dat) do ( 
    set /a count+=1
    %grep% --ignore-case -w "%%a" %fileindex%>>temp.dat
)
powershell -Command "(gc temp.dat) -replace '&amp;', '&' | sc list.dat"
del /f temp.dat
pause
exit /b
```

Some changed things:

- `set /a count+=1` = `set /a count=%count%+1`

  - The `!fileHash!` points to `%%a`, so why do we need it? `%%a` will work.
- The `powershell` command replaces `&amp;` with `&`.
- Output the replaced content into the file.
- Delete a temp file used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Steve!

I managed to get the exclamation marks problem solved based on what you wrote, but the ampersand still stands tho'

I use what you suggest me to do along with the label (replace) but the result is Echo is Off unfortunately.

Comment: I have made another edit to the script and should function as intended.

Comment: I've tried the updated one but it seems like it bypassed the replace subroutine now. I've added a simple echo and it doesn't shows up.  
  
An [Example](https://imgur.com/a/MgJZ5) of it.
  
At first I thought I just forgot the closing `)` but it seems not like it.

Comment: Two things: Why do you have delayed expansion on? You haven't set the `%grep%`.

Comment: Ooops, my apologies, forgot to re-add the grep variables value there. Still the same result though.  The test `echo lala` also doesn't [shows up](https://imgur.com/a/JMFfF).

Comment: Aww.. I found a missing closing bracket, which you also missed.

Comment: Oh, I already did that as well actually and it shows me the [document](https://imgur.com/TgKkwqX) for `call`.

Comment: That is absolutely weird as I don't get such error. Can you show an example output of the `grep` command?

Comment: [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/5nrwE) the output of both the command and the result if we to bypass the ampersand replace subroutine.

Comment: The solution has problems with carets and quotes, as the call doesn't handle them very well

Comment: @jeb Hmm... I gotta look into that later.